# GPS stationary mode support added in the latest release of GPSD 3.16?

Tags: gpsd

I read from [this](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/gpsd-time-service-howto.html#_choice_of_hardware) link.
with the following statement: 
 "For most reliable service we recommend using stationary mode if your device has it. GPSD tools don’t yet directly support this, but that capability may be added in a future release.."

Anyone know if the stationary mode has been added to the latest release of GPSD 3.16 ?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

It certainly does not look like it:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gpsd.git/log/?qt=grep&q=stationary

You can always send the appropriate config commands to the gps before starting gpsd.